# Exponential functions and volume/ surface area

Tags: functions

A pyramid has a square base of side $x$ metres. The perpendicular height of pyramid is $h$ metres. The volume of the pyramid is $1500\text{cm}^3$.

> a. Find the expression for the volume of the pyramid.
>
> b. Show that the height of each of the triangular faces is$$\sqrt{h^2+(x/2)^2}$$
>
> c. Hence find an equation for the total surface area of the
> pyramid.

I am struggling to figure out what to do in $(b)$ and $(c)$. Can anyone explain how to get the answers?

Comment: Can you post an image please?

Comment: In this case does "pyramid" mean a square base and for congruent triangular faces?  What have you tries and where is your issue.  If you look at the pyramid fro the side and take cross sections b and c are pretty obvious.  (It's a) that is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

For a) we get $$V=\frac{1}{3}x^2\cdot h$$ for b) The hight of each triangular surface is given by the theorem of Pythagorean: $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+h^2}=h_a$$ And so the total surface of our pyramid is given by $$A=4\cdot \frac{h_a}2\cdot x+x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Picture it in your mind.

The pyramid is four equilateral triangles tilting down.   Each of the triangle has a base of $x$ and a height of $q$ and a side of $s$.  We were told what $x$ is but we have no idea what $s$ and $q$ are.  Although we can relate $q$ and $s$ together via $(\frac 12x)^2 + q^2 = s^2$ that won't do us any good if we don't know what one or the other is.

b) is asking us to prove $q = \sqrt{h^2 + (\frac x2)^2}$.

Now, remember the trianglee is tipping to form a pyramid.  The tip of the triangle is tip of the pryamid so if you dropped straight down from there you get a height $h$.  Now if you go from the center of the floor directly to the midpoint of the triangle you have:  The height of the pyramid $h$; A line from the center of the floor to the middle of the base of a triangle; an the line height of the triangle $q$ that is tipping over.

These three line segments from a right triangle.  One side is the height of the pyramid $h$; the other is a line from the center of an $x \times x$ square to the midpoint of only of its side-- that is a distance of $\frac x2$; and the hypotenuse is the height of the triangle, $q$.

So $q^2 = h^2 + (\frac x2)^2$ or $q = \sqrt{h^2 + (\frac x2)^2}$.

c) total surface area of the pyramid is the area of the 4 triangles and the square base.  The area of the square base is $x^2$ and the area of the triangle faces is $\frac 12 x\times  \sqrt{h^2 + (\frac x2)^2}$ so the total area is $x^2  + 4\frac 12x\sqrt{h^2 + (\frac x2)^2}= x^2 + 2x \sqrt{h^2 + (\frac x2)^2}$.